# bash global variable not changed after inline operation

Tags: bash

I have a comma delimited string variable that I need to remove values that are coming from standard input, which is coming in from a file.  When I finish the script the values are not removed from the variable but you can tell that they were removed in the do loop.  How do I update a var that is global inside the do loop of the operation?

```
#!/bin/bash
    varFoo="text1,text2,obit,poodle,text2,text1,doberman,bloodhound,treewalker,breaker,circuit,bum,rush"
echo text2 > /tmp/fileFeed.txt
echo circuit >> /tmp/fileFeed.txt
echo rush >> /tmp/fileFeed.txt
cat /tmp/fileFeed.txt | while read word; do
    removeWord=${varFoo//$word,/}
    removeWord=${removeWord//,$word/}
    echo ========== transaction seperator ==========
    echo word=$word
    echo removeWord=$removeWord
    varFoo=$removeWord
done
echo ^^^^^^^^^^^exiting work loop and heading to the end ^^^^^^^^^^^
echo FINAL varFoo = $varFoo
exit $?
```

The output is

```
========== transaction seperator ==========
word=text2
removeWord=text1,obit,poodle,text1,doberman,bloodhound,treewalker,breaker,circuit,bum,rush
========== transaction seperator ==========
word=circuit
removeWord=text1,obit,poodle,text1,doberman,bloodhound,treewalker,breaker,bum,rush
========== transaction seperator ==========
word=rush
removeWord=text1,obit,poodle,text1,doberman,bloodhound,treewalker,breaker,bum
^^^^^^^^^^^exiting work loop and heading to the end ^^^^^^^^^^^
FINAL varFoo =     text1,text2,obit,poodle,text2,text1,doberman,bloodhound,treewalker,breaker,circuit,bum,rush
```

So you'll notice that the loop removes the value from the string but when it exits the loop the variable is still at the original value before entering the loop.

Comment: Well known issue — you've got a subshell because of the pipe.  A disadvantage of UUoC (Useless Use of `cat`).  You could also look up `shopt -s lastpipe`.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 but here, an array would seem like the obvious workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Here,

```
cat /tmp/fileFeed.txt | while read word; do
   ....
done
```

the while loop gets executed in a subshell. So the none of the variables' values will be available outside the loop. Change it to:

```
while read word; do
   ....
done < /tmp/fileFeed.txt
```

You may also be interested in reading [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: That’s a stale copy from way back. The primary location is http://iki.fi/era/unix/award.html